# Moving drupal site to the root of the server

Tags: .htaccess

I have finished my drupal site and about to launch it in the end. Now everything is in a subdirectory called www.mysite.com/drupal_test, to do that, I had to change one line in the .htaccess file:

```
uncomment #RewriteBase /drupal
```

and change to

```
RewriteBase /drupal_test
```

I realised that .htaccess and some of other files in drupal are hidden files. I just blindly uploaded it and can't really see it in the ftp.

Now, I am ready to move everything to the root. I suppose I have to change that line back. But will I lose all the hidden files if I move? I can re-upload .htaccess, but there so many other hidden file that I don't know, will I lose them?

Is there anything else I should do when I move the directory or is there a better/proper way to do so rather than dragging and dropping all the files to the root?

Sorry if the question is stupid, I only have one day left to do this and I am terrified by moving drupal sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can upload the new .htaccess file and change back the line `#RewriteBase` if you have modified only one line of the .htaccess file, there won't be any problem and even if the file exists there it will give you a option to replace.

Few things that you have remember while moving your site to root folder are:

- Put the site into maintenance mode so that user's posts, comments etc. doesn't gets lost.
- The `#RewriteBase` is uncommented when we use the drupal from the subdirectory. So if you are moving it to the root folder than I guess no need to modify this line. (Anyways you try you way also).
- If you have modified/using the $base_url in setting.php than don't forget it to update as well.log
- Clear the complete cache, and check the watchdog table data (dblog) at "/admin/reports/dblog" to make no page or anything is having issue.

Comment: I am not worried about .htaccess because I know it exists and I will upload it again. I am worrying about other hidden files that I am not aware of their existence. Will I lose them?

Comment: @the_summer_bee As fas as I know there are only two hidden files in hidden folder, one is .htaccess and another is .gitignore. And you dont need to worry about them as you can anytime upload the hidden file from fresh download of drupal setup

Comment: It seems that I have screwed something up, the console show the errors like:

Comment: GET http://www.thesite.com/drupal_test/modules/system/system.base.css?mtn3gy 503 (Service unavailable), so still tried to look for the subdirectory.

Comment: @the_summer_bee if I am not wrong than you have moved drupal to the root of server, if so than why are you having "drupal_test" folder next to the your domain?

Comment: Is this error in watchdog table: "/admin/reports/dblog"

Comment: no, in browser console.

Comment: It seems i can't delete it! I deleted, and it is still there

Comment: have you moved the files to the root, if so than I guess clearing the cache will solve your problem

Comment: if you are bot able to remove the file than try changing the file permission, also better to keep its copy as backup on local

Comment: How do I clean the cache? Now I can't access the admin panel, if I type ?q=user after the url, it automatically direct me to /drupal_test/user/login, Also, it showed in the console it cannot find many files including jquery (because it is still looking for drupal_test/...

Comment: do have drush installed?, if so than running "drush cc all" from command line will clear the cache

Comment: Another method is to log into your phpmyadmin select your cache_ tables and flush/empty them.

Comment: may be this can be helpful for deleting the cache manually: http://wordpressapi.com/delete-drupal-cache-manually-mysql/ ,would be good if you can take the backup of database before emptying the cache tables (to be on safer side)

Comment: I have a putty that I can write command lines there, but I am not very good at this. my IT people are not here today. So can you teach me how to clear the cache from the command lines in putty? I have root permission. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I can't access phpmyadmin, i don't know why, but it is not a shared server like we normally use. Our IT people is in charge, but they are not in the office today. Thanks

Comment: Can you have a look at the tutorial that explains how to install drush through putty: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drush/

Comment: One moment, if your server is on ubuntu than best way to install drush is typing this command: sudo apt-get install drush

Comment: Hi, I think it is Linux, I have downloaded it using wget from github, but when I want to unzip it using 'unzip master.zip', it tells me -bash: unzip: command not found

Comment: If your server is on Linux than best way to install drush is typing this command: `sudo apt-get install drush`  

And if this work than remove the downloaded zipped file

Comment: good, I installed drush using apt-get, the last three line is unpacking drush(from.../archives/drush_3.3-1_all.deb)... , processing triggers for man-db, setting up drush(3.3-1), but how can I know where my drush is?

Comment: Thats great, now need to worry about where it is installed. Only thing to do once installation is complete is typing this command: `drush cc all`

Comment: right, three errors on the command line: 1. A Drupal installation directory could not be found, 2. Command cache-clear needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need invoke drush from a more functional drupal environment to run this command, the drush command 'cc all' could not be found.

Comment: oh sorry, you need to navigate to the directory where you have drupal setup, for example if your drupal directory name is "test" than first navigate to the test directory by typing `cd /YOUR/DRUPAL/PATH` and than run the `drush cc all`

Comment: it is the root of the website

Comment: is it cd /var/www ?

Comment: yes, I set /var/www/# drush all, it said 'all' cache was cleared, but my site still doesn't change, in the console, it still looks for .../drupal_test/....

Comment: also the drupal directory name, something like `cd /var/www/YOUR_DRUPAL_DIRETCORY` , basically drush command works when you are inside your drupal directory

Comment: have you removed your `drupal_test` directory or not, also for how many files it is showing that error?

Comment: I have managed to remove the drupal_test, it is no longer there. I think somewhere in a file, it still set up a drupal_test old direction, I don't know what..

Comment: Can you once check the `base_url` in settings.php file if it is containing value as `YOURDOMAIN.com/drupal_test` than remove "drupal_test", also it very unlikely that any file contains "drupal_test" as path of file unless you manually have added it. Otherwise it is coming from database only and you would have to update the same in the database only without worrying about this present in any file

Comment: Hey! it worked, I think it is the cache! Thank you so much, I wish I could buy you a beer! :D